# Replacing rubber drain plug gasket with a crush washer

Tags: ford, oil-change, ranger

I changed my oil today, and replaced the rubber gasket that was starting to deteriorate with a crush washer. I was unable to find any info if this was acceptable, but I did see that similar washers were a fit for my make and model on the autozone site, so I went ahead and removed the rubber gasket and replaced it with the crush washer and torqued it to spec.

I'm now starting to question this decision without further info, as the gasket/o-ring was recessed..

Does anyone know if this is an okay swap out?

Truck is a 1996 FORD RANGER 4.0L V6

Comment: I’m assuming you are talking about a brass washer?  If so that is just fine.

Comment: I should mention that the gasket/o-ring was slightly recessed into the plug.. It wasn't brass, but it was a proper crush washer made for oil plugs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is ok to use other sealing washers as long as they do not leak.

I have always liked the nylon washers, they last much longer than rubber, brass, aluminum or copper.